# how can I see all running or blocked asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, blocking

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits) there is a limit on the number of running asynctasks. I'm using asynctasks in several activities and in each activity I cancel running asynctask (if any) before execute a new one. but still I have blocking problem and I doubt the asynctask are completely canceled. My question is that "is there any way to see all running and blocking asynctasks?"

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. **AsyncTask is execute In the ThreadPool**.  Before HoneyComb the default size is 5. after the default size is 1.
2. When you call the `AsyncTask.cancel()` . the Thread is not exactly cancelled.

Comment: Ok, but how can I see if the asynctask is not exactly cancelled. and more generally is there any way to see all the running asynctasks?