# android asynctask download files

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I have a list of items, when user clicks on one item,my app starts download a file from internet.
I use AsyncTask  for download a file.
Now I want download muitiple files(use Queue the extra file will be added to the Queue and will be downloaded later).How can I manage multiple AsyncTasks?

Note:I use API 8. I don't want to use Download Manager class in API 9

Comment: Create a new `AsyncTask` instance and pass it the next filename / URL

Comment: I'm trying to download multiple files one by one (file is downloaded, we start downloading the next file), . with your solution ,I have many Asynctasks download many file simultaneously

Comment: **"with your solution ,I have many Asynctasks download many file simultaneously"** - You said you want to down the next file "later" - you didn't say when, 1 minute later...2 minutes later etc. If you simply want to download a sequence of files just pass all the URLs to the `AsyncTask` and have it loop through them all.

Comment: Firstly,I have a list of items, when user clicks on one item,my app starts download a file from  internet. So I can't pass all the URLs to the AsysncTask(just one). I mean here use Queue the next file will be added to the Queue and will be downloaded immediately (start when file before it already download complete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about too many AsyncTasks causing issues, you dont need to.
Android automatically handles this from v1.6.
Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9654445/1627802)  for more info.

Additionally, if you do want to more control on execution and scheduling of task, use the [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) class