# How to limit the threads in the thread pool (Android)

Tags: android

When executing `AysncTask`, The following api I am using

```
executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"nameofpool");
```

Is it possible that somehow I can set only 2 threads limit in this pool.

Comment: Look at [Android AsyncTask threads limits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits).

Answer (score 3):

The `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` is a special pool that is created for you and administrated by Android.

You can, however, create your own `Executor`, typically using :

```
Executor myExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

which you can use in your `AsyncTask` :

```
executeOnExecutor(myExecutor, params);
```

Nota: please note that your param "nameofpool" is actually the parameter to the `doInBackground` method on your `AsyncTask`, and is not related to the Thread pool management.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide [your own executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29):

```
executeOnExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2), "nameofpool");
```