# running multiple AsyncTasks: task.executeOnExecutor not working

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a college project where I need to use threads to run tasks in paralel. I started using AsyncTask and the simple task.execute(params), but then I found out that this does not allow multiple Asynctasks to run, just one per time.
Then I discovered task.executeOnExecutor, which I use like this(code inside my ElevatorControl class):

```
taskDesligaLampada.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
```

I execute this in my ElevatorControl class(which is not an activity). The funny thing is: executeOnExecutor is not starting the doInBackground method of the task. I tried using Logging for debuggig like this(inside my AsyncTask):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... string_qualquer) 
{
    //PAREI AKI PARECE QUE ESSA TASK NÃO EXECUTA. PROBLEMA DO EXECUTE ON EXECUTOR?
    Log.i("ElevatorControl", "Elevador id=" + elevatorControl.getIdElevador() + ";fechando porta");
    this.interfaceDaPorta.fecharPorta(andarAtual, this.elevatorControl.getIdElevador());
    return "";
}
```

but the log does not appear on logCat, which means it's not running. Tried catching the State variable returned after executteOnExecutor like this(method inside my ElevatorControl task):

```
//os eventos abaixo deveriam ser concorrentes. Por isso as tasks foram criadas
    TaskFechaPorta taskFechaPorta = new TaskFechaPorta(this, interfaceDaPorta, sobeOuDesceOuParado, andarAtual);
    Status statusThreadRoda = taskFechaPorta.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "").getStatus();
```

and, by debugging, I found out that this Status is "running". The why is it not running the doInBackground method of my task?

can anyone say me what am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I use a LOT of asyncTasks for my project, at least 18 running because my teacher said so.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Android has a limit of Threads and AsyncTask.
"All AsyncTasks are controlled internally by a shared (static) ThreadPoolExecutor and a LinkedBlockingQueue. When you call execute on an AsyncTask, the ThreadPoolExecutor will execute it when it is ready some time in the future."

In this post:[Android AsyncTask threads limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits)

What the version of your Android? This feature is only available since Honeycomb.

Regards.