# Asynctask running only once in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to run asynctask every second but it works only one time.After it stopped working but handler is running every second.

I am using asynctask for insert data into database.

```
Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new PushRawData().execute();
            new PushGraphData().execute();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
        }
    };
```

Comment: need to use jobschedular.

Comment: what´s the value for INTERVAL ? Think about, AsyncTask can only run once at the same time. So, if your PushRawData() for example ist still running, the second call will not be executed....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Interval 1000

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Every second i am inserting data into database

Comment: for this, I guess you don´t need an asynctask, the handler is enough. For how long do you do it? The hole runtime the app is running? If yes, this is too much (is it really necessary?).

Comment: But app hang every second data insert

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask have limits, [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits)

You can try to increase the thread pool size

Jobscheduler does not guarantee to run every second, its purpose is different

You can use content provider  and cursor loaders, they run on background thread without affection the ui ie main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Use Service for continuous operations in background.Refer to the below information.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html