# Thread android blocking maximum

Tags: java, android, multithreading, blocking

I have 10 AsyncTask Thread try to insert into queue but when the queue is full the thread must keep waiting until it's free again.

So I have tried to create them and when I try to create 10 more thread that will consume the queue they aren't even created so what is the maximum number of thread can be run concurrent and keep in mind the first 10 thread are waiting by while loop until the queue is free to add.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [Android AsyncTask threads limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits)

Excerpt from the link,

> Before Android 1.6, the core pool size was 1 and the maximum pool size
>   was 10. Since Android 1.6, the core pool size is 5, and the maximum
>   pool size is 128. The size of the queue is 10 in both cases. The
>   keep-alive timeout was 10 seconds before 2.3, and 1 second since then.