# AsyncTask maximum time limit allowed

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask

What is the maximum time the Android ecosystem allows an `AsyncTask` task to run?

I have been asked this question many times in interviews, but I've never found a concrete answer.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a fixed max time limit, at least from a technical perspective.  An `AsyncTask` can run for an unlimited amount of time.

This can lead to a number of problems.

If you execute the `AsyncTask` by calling `execute()`, then they are run serially - that is, one after another, never running multiple at the same time.  If you use `execute()` and your tasks runs for too long, you'll prevent other tasks run that way from executing until you're done
If you execute it with `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`, it's slightly better, though it will still run a very limited number of tasks ([varying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits) based on various factors) in parallel.

In these situations, things could happen like a couple slow web requests (or entering a subway tunnel and the internet slowing down) could prevent *all* `AsyncTask`s in your app from running.

For this and other reasons, **it is *recommended, but not enforced*, that `AsyncTask`s should not be used for anything other than relatively quick tasks**, such as fast web requests or database reads.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would say in the interview, is that the AsyncTask is deprecated in API 30:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Then I would use some of the answers from this question:
[Android AsyncTask threads limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits)

And in the end I would say something about Kotlin coroutines as the alternative:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Comment: I know that, but still, there is if something is deprecated doesn't mean one should not have some typical knowledge of that component.
Again I would like to have a concrete answer.